# Find out the email of a user?

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to find out the email of a certain user.

I tried:

```
hg log --user sherman
```

but that only told me all the changes that *sherman* made and didn't tell me his email.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the user hasn't provided an email at all when committing, but if they have this might help although it'll not give you the result for a single user.

`hg churn -c --template "{author|person} - {author|email}"`

Should give you a list of all the authors in the format

`username - email_address`

It'll also give you the number of commits they've made.

---

Another option that'll give you similar output (in Powershell) without the churn extension is:

`hg log --template "{author|person} - {author|email}\n" | Sort-Object -Unique`

I believe the Linux equivalent is something like:

`hg log --template "{author|person} - {author|email}\n" | sort | uniq`